# Does unfiltered coffee raise cholesterol

Tags: cholesterol

My friend told me that unfiltered coffee may raise my cholesterol.  I am carefully watching my diet to reduce cholesterol by my Doctor's recommendation.

If stopping drinking unfiltered coffee can reduce my cholesterol, I would like to give it a try. First thing to stop is to avoid whip creame and sugar into my Latte.

Any advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the oils in coffee (terpenes, in particular kahweol and cafestol) are believed to be the source of its effect on cholesterol.<sup>[[1](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/6242467/ns/health-heart_health/t/coffee-cholesterol/), [2](http://www.drweil.com/drw/u/QAA401225/Does-Coffee-Raise-Cholesterol.html), [3](http://atvb.ahajournals.org/content/11/3/586.long), [4](http://www.nature.com/ejcn/journal/v57/n9/full/1601668a.html)]</sup>

There are two ways to cut down on intake of cholesterol-influencing terpenes:

1. **Switch to filtered coffee.**  The terpenes are mostly retained in the paper filter instead of going into your drink. At the same time, cut down on the cream and sugar, as you already noted ;)
2. **Quit drinking coffee completely.** Even filtered coffee still has *some* terpenes present, and therefore can still impact cholesterol levels. Filtered coffee is a significant improvement — "serum cholesterol raising effect of unfiltered coffee ... is reduced by about 80% in filtered coffee"<sup>[[4](http://www.nature.com/ejcn/journal/v57/n9/full/1601668a.html)]</sup> — but if you're being very rigorous about watching your dietary cholesterol intake, it may be time to quit.

---

For further reading, some sources are below. The fourth (Strandhagen and Thelle 2003) has a number of additional studies in its introduction.

1. [Coffee and Cholesterol: Does your daily morning jolt boost the risk of heart disease?](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/6242467/ns/health-heart_health/t/coffee-cholesterol/) (NBC News)
2. [Does Coffee Raise Cholesterol?](http://www.drweil.com/drw/u/QAA401225/Does-Coffee-Raise-Cholesterol.html) (Dr. Andrew Weil)
3. van Dusseldorp et al. [Cholesterol-raising factor from boiled coffee does not pass a paper filter.](http://atvb.ahajournals.org/content/11/3/586.long) *Arteriosclerosis, Thrombosis, and Vascular Biology.* 1991 May-Jun;11(3):586-93
4. E Strandhagen and D S Thelle. [Filtered coffee raises serum cholesterol: results from a controlled study.](http://www.nature.com/ejcn/journal/v57/n9/full/1601668a.html) *European Journal of Clinical Nutrition* (2003) 57, 1164–1168.